# How to debug a project using 'Unmanaged Exports' nuget package

Tags: c#, unmanagedexports

I have an SDK Style .net472 project using `unmanagedexports.repack\1.0.4\`

The exports work correctly, but whenever I try to attach a debugger, or debug via unittest, Visual Studio will ask me:

`Find Source: {projectName}.il`

How can I resolve this issue? If I remove the package debugging works again.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by

1. Using `DLLExport` package instead of `UnmanagedExports`
2. Using `AnyCPU` instead of `x86`
3. In `DLLExport` configuration, select `x86+x64`
4. Use the files in the `x86` output bin folder

The `AnyCpu` is required as a workaround for now, as `DLLExport` will exhibit the same behavior as the original post if just targeting `x86`, in current version 1.7.4